# Tabulating multiple responses

Tags: stata

In a survey to improve quality of video dissemination of agricultural practices, one of the variables is which of the non-negotiable practices were discussed during the dissemination. For example, sowing of wheat has four non-negotiable practices mentioned in it.

I want to create a variable which returns 4, 3, 2 or 1 depending on which of the practices were discussed.

I first coded all the string responses into numeric:

```
gen SWI_ST_NNG1=q205_1_1
replace SWI_ST_NNG1="0" if SWI_ST_NNG1=="#NULL!"
replace SWI_ST_NNG1="1" if SWI_ST_NNG1=="Luke warm water should be used for seed treatment"

gen SWI_ST_NNG2=q205_1_2
replace SWI_ST_NNG2="0" if SWI_ST_NNG2=="#NULL!"
replace SWI_ST_NNG2="2" if SWI_ST_NNG2=="Mixture of seed, Jaggery and cow urine should kept for"

gen SWI_ST_NNG3=q205_1_3
replace SWI_ST_NNG3="0" if SWI_ST_NNG3=="#NULL!"
replace SWI_ST_NNG3="3" if SWI_ST_NNG3=="Use of bavistin powder is must for seed treatment"

gen SWI_ST_NNG4=q205_1_4
replace SWI_ST_NNG4="0" if SWI_ST_NNG4=="#NULL!"
replace SWI_ST_NNG4="4" if SWI_ST_NNG4=="Seeds should be kept 12 to 15  hours for germination"
```

Comment: Open the editor to see how to format code.

Comment: That is: (1) highlight a block of code (2) click on the `{}` icon to format it.

Answer (score 0):

We need a sandbox to make things clear, as you didn't provide a MCVE. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Essentially, variable *j* in a series has values either *j* (1 to 4) or 0, and I think you want to **count** the non-zeros. (I don't see that returning 1 to 4 makes any sense otherwise, because how would you code 1 and 3 from one person and 4 from another?)

A count is easily done with a loop across variables.

```
clear
set obs 10 
set seed 2803 
forval j = 1/4 { 
    gen SWI_ST_NNG`j' = cond(runiform() < 0.5, `j', 0) 
} 

list, sep(0) 


     +-------------------------------------------+
     | SWI_ST~1   SWI_ST~2   SWI_ST~3   SWI_ST~4 |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  1. |        0          0          0          4 |
  2. |        1          0          0          0 |
  3. |        0          2          0          0 |
  4. |        1          2          3          4 |
  5. |        1          2          3          4 |
  6. |        1          2          3          0 |
  7. |        1          2          3          0 |
  8. |        0          2          3          4 |
  9. |        1          0          3          4 |
 10. |        1          2          3          0 |
     +-------------------------------------------+

gen count = 0 

quietly forval j = 1/4 { 
    replace count = count + (SWI_ST_NNG`j' > 0) 
}

list, sep(0)

     +---------------------------------------------------+
     | SWI_ST~1   SWI_ST~2   SWI_ST~3   SWI_ST~4   count |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
  1. |        0          0          0          4       1 |
  2. |        1          0          0          0       1 |
  3. |        0          2          0          0       1 |
  4. |        1          2          3          4       4 |
  5. |        1          2          3          4       4 |
  6. |        1          2          3          0       3 |
  7. |        1          2          3          0       3 |
  8. |        0          2          3          4       3 |
  9. |        1          0          3          4       3 |
 10. |        1          2          3          0       3 |
     +---------------------------------------------------+
```

For much more on working rowwise, see [this discussion](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0046).

In practice, there is a convenient short-cut:

```
egen count2 = anycount(SWI*), values(1/4)
```

but learning about the looping method is really useful for cracking more complicated problems.

Note that if you had coded variables as just 1 or 0 then the count you want would just have been the row sum, easily obtained with `egen`. Such indicator (a.k.a. dummy) variables are for most statistical and data management purposes a much better coding.